# XOR operation between two logical operations

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I am trying to implement the following operation:

```
(alpha >> 3) XOR (beta >> 5)
```

Where `>>` is the shift right operator.

This is what I have so far:

```
org 100h 

   mov AX, 1A26h ;alpha
   mov BX, 553Fh ;beta 

compareAX:
    cmp AX,3
    ja compare BX
    mov CX,AX

compareBX:
    cmp BX,5
    ja continue
    mov DX, BX   

continue:


int 20h
```

I really don't know how to implement the XOR or if the comparison above is correct. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is `>>` a comparison operator or a bitshift operator?

Comment: @RaymondChen it is the shift right operator.

Comment: Try it with a compiler, maybe https://godbolt.org.

Comment: For the `alpha >> 3`, it makes no sense to compare alpha against the shift count.  Just shift it by 3 with SHR or SAR, depending on whether you want logical or arithmetic right shift.  There are no compares in the expression you're trying to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
shr ax,3
shr bx,5
xor ax,bx
; The result of (alpha >> 3) XOR (beta >> 5) is in AX
```